# Show logged in users from yesterday

Tags: command-line, osx

I am new to Unix and am writing a shell to show users that have been logged in since only the previous day. Instructions say to use the command last -s `-1 day' but -s is longer functional. Know of any alternatives?

Comment: looks like the last from `util-linux` does `-s` as you want (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/last.1@@util-linux.html) and `last` from `psacct` project does `-s` as "show time in seconds".

Comment: Sorry I meant to take out the linux tag. I am using \bin\bash on mac terminal

Comment: Is your coursework expected to be run on a Linux-system? The answer would be very easy there but considerably harder on OSX (Mac).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it very nicely using

```
last --since yesterday
```

which will show you, users still logged in, times of reboot, tty consoles open and other nice and useful information. Like this :

```bsh
    $ last -R --since 2019-10-23   
    root     tty7         Thu Oct 24 13:10   still logged in
    reboot   system boot  Thu Oct 24 13:09   still running
    root     tty1         Wed Oct 23 23:13 - crash  (13:56)
    root     tty7         Wed Oct 23 23:11 - 23:25  (00:13)
    reboot   system boot  Wed Oct 23 23:11   still running
```

`last` reads from `/var/log/wtmp` which is actually a dBase file and not a regular text log file. One nice thing it actually reports is whether a reboot caused a power outage apparently (hence the still running flag)